# Proving monotonicity of measure

Tags: measure-theory

I need help understanding the proof provided for this statement:

> Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$. Prove that if $A
>  \subset B$, then $\mu(A) \leq \mu(B)$

Here's the proof in Durrett's Probability Theory book:

Using $+$ to denote disjoint union, write $B = A + (B - A)$ so that

$$\mu(B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B - A) \geq \mu(A).$$

But I'm curious as to how they are able to write $B = A + (B - A)$. If $+$ is the disjoint union, then $A$ is everything in $A$ and $(B - A)$ is everything in $B$ that isn't in $A$. So wouldn't this just be the same thing as $A \cup B$, which of course isn't equal to $B$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A\cup B$ is the same as $B$ because it is given that $A \subseteq B$.